# InvokeMainThread Xamarin

Tags: c#, thread, xamarin, task

estou com um problema ao invocar uma UIThread no PCL.

Fiz um método assim:

```
    private void PopularConteudo()
    {

        Task<List<Departamento>> taskDep = new Task<List<Departamento>>(() =>
        {
            departamentos = departamentoDal.GetAll();
            return departamentos.ToList();
        });
        taskDep.Start();
        taskDep.Wait();

        PopularCarouselDepartamentos();

        Task<List<Categoria>> taskCat = new Task<List<Categoria>>(() =>
        {
            categorias = categoriaDal.GetAllByDepartamento(carouselViewDepartamentos.Item as Departamento).ToList();
            PopularCarouselCategorias();
            return categorias.ToList();
        });

        taskCat.Start();
        taskCat.Wait();

        Task<List<Produto>> taskProd = new Task<List<Produto>>(() =>
        {
            produtos = produtoDal.GetAllByCategoria(carouselViewCategorias.Item as Categoria);
            return produtos.ToList();
        });
        taskProd.Start();
        taskProd.Wait();
        PopularListViewProdutos();
    }

private void PopularCarouselDepartamentos()
{

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=> {
            try
            {
                carouselViewDepartamentos.ItemsSource = departamentos;
            }
            catch (Exception e) // handle whatever exceptions you expect
            {
                //Handle exceptions
            }
        });
}
```

O que acontece é o seguinte, quando eu invoco o método PopularCarouselDepartamentos() ele simplesmente não entra no bloco de instrução try-catch.

Consequentemente o Carousel não é populado e eu preciso dele pra popular os outros conteúdos.

Todos os métodos de popular são bem parecidos.

Alguém sabe como solucionar esse problema?

Comment: O método PopularConteudo é async mas em nenhum momento existe um await dentro dele. Talvez isso possa ser um dos problemas. Eu pensaria numa refatoração onde os metodos de consulta (Get alguma coisa) ja fossem assíncronos, acredito que seria mais simples para gerenciar isso :)

Comment: Desculpe, eu copiei o código errado, o novo já está sem o async.

Comment: O que eu acho que está aconcento é que ele está executando todas as Tasks antes de realizar o método BeginInvokeOnMainThread(), no entanto eu preciso parar a Task quando ela popular minha lista para posteriormente invocar na UI Thread a atualização da lista. No entanto isso não está acontecendo.

Comment: Executa de forma síncrona para testar!

Comment: Como posso fazer ? Basta chamar o task.RunSynchronously(); Agradeço.

Comment: Chame a categoriaDal e produtosDal normalmente, fora da Task, faça esse teste...

Comment: Bom dia amigo, fiz e não deu certo, o código continua pulando a tarefa de executar o bloco try/catch. Se eu tirar esse processamento da Task, eu perco um pouco em desempenho, a idéia era separar as consultas em uma Task normal e as alterações gráficas na UIThread, o problema é que eu dependo do resultado da UIThread. Se eu tirar o processamento das Tasks de categoria e produto, seria mais conveninente manter tudo sem Task. Obrigado pela atenção.